# Python formatting mongodb data

Tags: python

I very new to python and mongodb and struggling to write simple query to summarize a data. I need help in term of python to format the output I get from mongodb query. Final output is something like this..

```
Day     C1    C2    C3    C4
 1      123   125  122    254 
 2       123   125  122    254
 3       123   125  122    254
```

The data from the query I got is like this

```
[{u'total': 9942806, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c1'}},
 {u'total': 10173832, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c2'}},
 {u'total': 9567489, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c3'}}]
```

First problem i got is, the key for row and column is inside '_id' list. d is for Day (row), and 'sid' is for Column. The value will be 'total'.

I can loop the data to be flatten, something like

```
Day    SID    Total
```

but to re-arrange the output to be like a table I wanted is out of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to pretty print your data as a table:

```
data = [{u'total': 9942806, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c1'}},
 {u'total': 10173832, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c2'}},
 {u'total': 9567489, u'_id': {u'd': 1, u'sid': u'c3'}}]

print("Day\tSID\tTotal")
for l in data:
    print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(l['_id']['d'], l['_id']['sid'], l['total']))
```

though please read http://sscce.org to know how to correctly ask a question, and we expect people asking questions on SO to give an example of code they did to *try* to solve their problem instead of just asking for others to do it for them.